# buffer overflow does not happen when it should?

Tags: loops, for-loop, overflow, buffer

yesterday I came across a bug in my proggy I couldn't make head or tail of. After hours of work with the software it suddenly crashed and showed me the following type of message (maybe not the same because I was only able to reproduce it one time and didn't save the message - but it was a BEX error, used another code snippet for it, see further below):

```
Problemsignatur:
  Problemereignisname:  BEX
  Anwendungsname:   ----.exe
  Anwendungsversion:    0.0.0.0
  Anwendungszeitstempel:    5059a92f
  Fehlermodulname:  ----.exe
  Fehlermodulversion:   0.0.0.0
  Fehlermodulzeitstempel:   5059a92f
  Ausnahmeoffset:   0000cae3
  Ausnahmecode: c0000417
  Ausnahmedaten:    00000000
  Betriebsystemversion: 6.0.6000.2.0.0.---.-
  Gebietsschema-ID: 1031
  Zusatzinformation 1:  d752
  Zusatzinformation 2:  becd3a3c3e2751afee56698a1f79a48e
  Zusatzinformation 3:  4c74
  Zusatzinformation 4:  91af6395315cadbb5a06842f28b0d430
```

so when I found out that this is an buffer overflow error I tried figuring out where that buffer overflow would occur. I came up with a for loop that shouldn't work and cause such an error. The type of issue is something along the lines of this:

```
int bob=0;int pop;
for(pop=0;pop<bob;pop++){cout<<pop;}
```

except that instead of cout the pop value is used to fill an array with elements. I initilized it here with zero just to demonstrate, in the program bob can be changed by the user to a value >0 but the for loop is continuously called no matter if bob is zero or !=0. When I execute the code above the proggy immediately crashes (as expected) while in the actual case it didn't, only after a long time, even when I used the cout command to check if the for loop is indeed executed. Maybe this is because the code is inside a function and that function is called from inside a while loop?

So my question is, is this the most probable cause for the buffer overflow or should I look somewhere else. I really have no idea what other issue could cause this sporadic and very annoying error.

Answer (score 0):

There is no infinite loop in the provided example.

Values before the first iteration are:
 bob = 0;
 pop = 0;

Because 0 (pop) is not less than 0 (bob), pop < bob returns false and for loop should not execute. If for loop is executing, check the value of bob. Perhaps you have placed the variable initialization for bob in a code path that does not execute.

I personally would recommend using a debugger.

Comment: as I had said I've checked if the for loop is indeed executing by writing a cout command inside the for loop: cout<<bob and it showed me a 0. But that only works inside my proggy, not in the example above. I have no idea why.

Comment: Obviously the problem is not in the code you posted here. Without knowing what your code does and how it does it, it's impossible to say what is going wrong.

Is there a reason why you can't use a debugger?

Comment: meanwhile I was able to reproduce the error message and I think I've fixed it now. The error message btw is the same as shown above which I received by executing above code snippet. So it's indeed hard to tell from such a message what actually went wrong. Nevertheless, I still have no clue why the for loop is executed one time and another time it is not. Maybe because it's inside a function which again is called from within a while loop. I simply put it into an if exclusion (if (bob>0)) so it cannot be the cause of a possible buffer overflow anymore.